# Is there any way to know which job will start next in qsub

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, qsub, supercomputers

In our institute (IISc Bangalore)Supercomputer ,we submit jobs using qsub. The jobs will start running according to the following-

(1) Its wall time(Expected completion time)

(2) Its position in the respected queue(small,medium,large etc).

So,it is very difficult to know which job will start after finishing one job which is currently running. But qsub is probably has a list of its own,by which it is starting a new job after finishing another job immediately.
Is there any way to know which job will start next.Is there any command for this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no clear way to know which job will be run next in a supercomputing system. The job start is depending not only on it's wall time or position in the queue but also many other factors based on the site-level policy, scheduling strategies and priorities. There can be some internal job ranking (priorities) chosen by the institute based on factors like power management, load balancing etc.

On the other side, there are many researches to predict the waiting time for job allocation. TeraGrid systems provides estimated waiting time. Also, see [link1](https://books.google.de/books?id=5xWoBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=serc%20job%20scheduling%20strategy&source=bl&ots=rmA3cHgSPf&sig=ACfU3U3ru7F4c5IiWktkgbqTHiJ7ZDmOLQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXqaj5l5_qAhV05KYKHSzJDlUQ6AEwAXoECA4QAQ#v=onepage&q=serc%20job%20scheduling%20strategy&f=false), [link2](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-35867-8_11) (by SERC) for more information about predicting the waiting time.